# Select lowest value from select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables all with one to many relations

Product

```
id | slug |
1  | 1-a  |
2  | 2-a  |
3  | 3-a  |
```

Product Sku

```
id | product_id |
1  |     1      |
2  |     1      |
3  |     2      |
```

Product Image

```
id | product_sku_id | rank |
1  |     1          |   0  |
2  |     2          |   1  |
3  |     3          |   0  |
```

What I am trying to do is in a single query return the Product.slug and the Product_Image.id with the lowest rank.

What I am working with right now is Doctrine and I can't have a subquery in a join in Doctrine so what I am trying to figure out is how to get the correct product Image to associate with the product.

```
SELECT
  p.slug,pi.id
FROM
  product p
JOIN
  product_sku ps
ON
  p.id = ps.product_id
JOIN
  product_image pi
ON
  ps.id = pi.product_sku_id
GROUP BY
  p.slug
```

using a subselect seems wrong:

```
SELECT
      p.slug,pi.id
    FROM
      product p
    JOIN
      product_sku ps
    ON
      p.id = ps.product_id
    JOIN
      (SELECT
        pi.*
        product_image pi
      ORDER BY
        pi.rank ) as pi
    ON
      ps.id = pi.product_sku_id
    GROUP BY
      p.slug
```

My Doctrine so far:

```
$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('DISTINCT p.slug,p.id')
    ->join('p.productSkus', 'ps)
    ->join('ps.productImages','pi');
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: This is an overly simplified query of what I am trying to accomplish there is a lot more going on that doesn't affect the question but requires me to use something other than NATIVE SQL I just put in the SQL to show what I can get to work.

Comment: Can you use a subselect in the WHERE clause? If not, take a look at a very old MySQL manual (4.0 or older). Those versions didn't support subselects and the manual showed some not nice looking tips how to do it without.

Comment: why do you need to join to the Product sku table?  I don't see it being used.

Comment: @TMcKeown It is how the product table and the product image table are associated

Comment: Please, could you post your entities code??

Comment: Have you tried using `$em->createQuery()` instead of `createQueryBuilder()` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  p.slug,pi.id
FROM
  product p
JOIN
  product_sku ps
ON
  p.id = ps.product_id
JOIN
  product_image pi
ON
  ps.id = pi.product_sku_id
GROUP BY
  p.slug
HAVING min(pi.rank)
```

Comment: You need something to ensure that the product_image.id is for the corresponding rank. Also, should probably group on product.id, not slug, and complete your `HAVING` clause.

Comment: What do you expect of your HAVING clause without a comparison operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an anti-join:

```
SELECT p.slug, pi.id
FROM product p
JOIN product_sku ps
  ON ps.product_id = p.id
JOIN product_image pi
  ON pi.product_sku_id = ps.id
LEFT JOIN product_image pi2
  ON pi2.product_sku_id = ps.id AND pi2.rank < pi.rank
WHERE pi2.rank IS NULL
```

However, you haven't said what to do with ties, so in the case of ties, it returns more than one record. To only get one image id per slug in the case of ties, then you could use `GROUP BY` and let MySQL pick one:

```
SELECT p.slug, pi.id
FROM product p
JOIN product_sku ps
  ON ps.product_id = p.id
JOIN product_image pi
  ON pi.product_sku_id = ps.id
LEFT JOIN product_image pi2
  ON pi2.product_sku_id = ps.id AND pi2.rank < pi.rank
WHERE pi2.rank IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id
```